# Sending data using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        getData();
    });
});

function getData() {
    var promise = testAjax('example2.aspx');
    displaySTSummaryData(promise);
}

function testAjax(theURL) {
    var person = {
        Name: 'happy',
        age: '21'
    };
    return $.ajax({
        url: theURL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: person
    });
}

function displaySTSummaryData(x) {
    x.success(function result(data) {
        $("div").html(data);
    });
}
```

In the above code I am sending data to example2.aspx. I can use only jquery aspx ajax. How can i display details of (Person (being sent ) on example2.aspx.

Comment: Specify your function which is take the parameter named as Name:'' And Age

Comment: thats what i need to know. I am very new to asp. Do i need to define a function in code behind of exampl2.aspx? I tried response.direct and querystring but the ajax does not work

Comment: Please refer this code and apply to your according http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Comment: thanks nayeem that is good code to refer.

Comment: I will definitely keep you updated. just halfway through.

Comment: Thanks a lot Nayeem. I have managed to display the data from second page using that asp snippets :-)

Comment: Most welcome ..:) i am always try to post correct solution which is ask by user..

Answer (score 0):

I would erase displaySTSummaryData function and add:

```
function testAjax(theURL) {
     var person = { Name: 'happy', age: '21' };
     return $.ajax
     ({
         url: theURL,
         type: 'POST',
         data: person
         success: function(e){
             $("div").html(e);
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear. I can populate data in my example.aspx where ajax is defined. I need to display the same data in example2.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call a static function in `.aspx`. Use like

```
function testAjax(theURL) {
    var person = {
        Name: 'happy',
        age: '21'
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: "example2.aspx/GetData",
        type: 'POST',
        data: person,
        success: function (data) {
            $("div").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

In aspx,

```
public static string GetData(string Name, int age) {
    return "Name :" + Name + ",Age:" + age;
}
```

You can use the `success` event of ajax to populate the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function displaySTSummaryData(x) {
    x.done(function (data) {
        $("div").html(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: sorry but it does not help.

Comment: `function getData() {
    var promise = testAjax('example2.aspx');
    promise.done(function (e) {  $("div").html(e); });}`

Comment: it does not make any difference

Comment: Basically on document.ready(function) of example2.aspx i want to display the details of person, which i am sending from ajax.